# python program to manipulate a list of items using class

Tags: python, list, oop

I am a newbie to python OOP concept. I need to write a program to manipulate a list of items(add, delete and display) using class. Without class i got output in this way :

```
def add():
    b=input("How many inputs? : ")
    print b
    if b==1:
        in1=input("Enter item : ")
        a.append(in1)
    else:
        in2=input("Enter items : ")
        a.extend(in2)
    print a

def delete():
    c=input("which item to delete? ")
    global a
    a=[x for x in a if x != c]
    print a

def display():      
    print a

ans=True
global a
a=[1,2,3,5,2]
while ans:
    print ("""
    1.Add items
    2.Delete items
    3.Display items
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=raw_input("What would you like to do? ") 
    if ans=="1": 
        add()
    elif ans=="2":
        delete()
    elif ans=="3":
        display() 
    elif ans=="4":
        print("\n Goodbye") 
        exit()
    else:
      print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
```

Can anyone help me to write the same code using class?

Comment: No. That's not what we do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all your functions in a class....

The advantage to the class approach is that you can have multiple lists being manipulated at once, and when you use a class, it doesn't depend on an arbitrary global list name you have picked.

Additionally, you were using the `input` method. As it seems you're using Python 2.7 (judging from your `print` statements), [you should be using `raw_input`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) `input` tries to `eval` what it gets back, whereas you just want the raw string that the user has entered, which is what `raw_input` returns.

```
 class ItemList:
        def __init__(self, list):
            self.a = list

        def add(self):
            b=raw_input("How many inputs? : ")
            print b
            if b==1:
                in1=raw_input("Enter item : ")
                self.a.append(in1)
            else:
                in2=raw_input("Enter items : ")
                self.a.extend(in2)
            print self.a

        def delete(self):
            c=raw_input("which item to delete? ")
            self.a=[x for x in a if x != c]
            print self.a

        def display(self):      
            print self.a


ans = True
a=[1,2,3,5,2]
myList = ItemList(a)
while ans:
    print ("""
    1.Add items
    2.Delete items
    3.Display items
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=raw_input("What would you like to do? ") 
    if ans=="1": 
        myList.add()
    elif ans=="2":
        myList.delete()
    elif ans=="3":
        myList.display() 
    elif ans=="4":
        print("\n Goodbye") 
        exit()
    else:
      print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
```

Comment: Thanq..it helped..yeah..i am using 2.7 version..tanq for the gud info..but input takes integer and raw_input for string input na ? I am sorry if itz useless question..itz only months i am into programming..

Comment: @NooNaMarJa I'm not sure what you're asking. The link I provided can probably help some. `input` does only work for numbers (in your case at least), whereas `raw_input` works for other things too. I figured you might want to add strings or other data to your list besides just numbers.